# strcmp not working for fgets file read input string

Tags: c

I am reading words from file & need to search some specific words, below is my code

```
string read = malloc(50 * sizeof(char));

FILE* p = fopen("word","r");

while(fgets(read,50,p))
{
    printf("%s\n",read);
    if(strcmp(read,"apple") == 0)
     {
        printf("apple found\n");
        break;
     }
}
```

And sample file 'word' is as below,

```
$: more word

liol
apple
scizzors
big
bang
mentalist
scapegrace
goat
goti
```

Why is strcmp not working in this case, printf can print string read, so char pointer is working fine.

Comment: @hivert: I think you updated this post in a manner that changed the actual problem (and in fact, probably solved it). OP showed the input file as a single line of words. You changed it to a separate line for each word. It makes all answers below irrelevant.

Comment: @barak manos : The newline between the word where there before my edit (see the [history](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/22280813/revisions)), I only made them **apparent**. So I don't think I changed the meaning of the original question.

Comment: @hivert: OK, gotcha, sorry...

Comment: @barak manos , sorry my bad, the file word is actually like hivert has modified, anyways , understood the concept of fgets using below answers!

Comment: You might as well get rid of the `malloc` while you're at it... just use `char read[50]` instead (or if you insist on `read = malloc`, then at least `free(read)` at the end.

Comment: @barakmanos manos  Yes, I have a habit of freeing space allocated by malloc, I also use 'valgrind' to check memory leakage for bigger programs.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `fgets()` function, in most circumstances, retains the newline at the end of the line. Hence `yourtext\n` will not compare equal to `yourtext`. You would have noted this with one of my favorite tricks for checking strings:

```
printf ("[%s]\n", read);
```

The presence of a newline before the closing `]` would have immediately alerted you to the problem, or at a minimum raised an eyebrow.

If you want to strip a newline off before comparing, you can do something like:

```
int ln = strlen (read);
if ((ln > 0) && (read[ln-1] == '\n'))
    read[ln-1] = '\0';
```

Alternatively, you could skip that and just do:

```
if (strcmp (read,"apple\n") == 0)
```

It's not necessarily elegant but, if you don't need to use the word for anything other than that comparison, it'll be just fine.

However, you may then need to worry about the last line in the file in case it has no newline at the end of it so maybe it's better to use the newline-removing code above.

Comment: Lets say I want to use 'read' for more than comparison, like encryption using some technique, do I need to remove '\n' from it then?

Comment: @amitfreeman, probably, only you can really answer that. Encryption of `apple` will almost certainly _not_ be the same as encryption of `apple\n`.

Comment: Note that on Linux you might also need to remove the carriage return `\r` So something like `if(read[ln-2] == '\r') read[ln-2] = '\0';`

Answer (score 2):

To search for a specific string in the line, rather than match the entire line, `strncmp` (which searches for n characters) can be used.

```
if (strncmp(read,"apple",strlen("apple")) == 0)
 {
    printf("apple found\n");
    break;
 }
```

Comment: @amitfreeman if you like the answer, consider to accept it

Comment: Hmmm. That code looks for words that start with "apple". To search for a string in a line (or _match_ it), you'd have to use `strstr`. (Anyway, the problem were the new-line charactres, I think.)